# How to get the exact location(Latitude and Longitude) of us using python?

Tags: python, python-requests, latitude-longitude

I want to find the coordinates of the location where i am living right now. I tried using a code like this:

```
send_url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json'
r = requests.get(send_url)
j = json.loads(r.text)
lat = j['latitude']
lon = j['longitude']
```

It is giving me the city coordinates. But i want the coordinates of my location right now. How to get that?

Comment: I'd use this: https://www.whataremycoordinates.com/

Comment: do i have to replace the url in the above code?

Comment: You'd have to get the html of the page and then parse it. I'll post an example.

Comment: yeah please, it would be useful

Comment: How do you think computers or a web site know your exact location?

Comment: that is what i am asking. Is it possible?

Comment: @Thedeadman619, you don't need to use the `json` module to parse the JSON response. Use the built-in [`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) function.

Comment: *How to get the exact location(Latitude and Longitude) of us?* I don't think that's a programming question. You're question translates to - *Which website can I use to find my current location?*

Comment: Thanks for translating my question @KeyurPotdar

Comment: Google Maps is able to. Might be able to simulate it with phantomjs

Comment: Are there any APIs to do this task?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
from selenium import webbrowser
a=webdriver.Chrome()
a.get("https://www.google.com/maps")
print(a.execute_script("window.location"))
```

Comment: It is not working for me. It is displaying None as the result. I am using webdriver of selenium

Comment: Huh. Worked for me

Comment: Could you please me with window.location

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import json
import time

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

string = '''
   function getLocation(callback) {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var myjson = {"latitude":position.coords.latitude, "longitude":position.coords.longitude};
                console.log(position);
                console.log(position.coords.latitude);
                console.log(position.coords.longitude); 
                var stringJson = JSON.stringify(myjson);
                callback(stringJson);
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
        }
    }
    
    getLocation(function(callback) {
        console.log(callback);
        const para = document.createElement("p");
        para.innerHTML = callback;
        para.id = "location";
        document.body.appendChild(para);
    });'''.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')


# repeat this code
driver.execute_script(string)
time.sleep(2)
res = driver.find_element(By.ID, "location")
loc = res.text
locDict = json.loads(loc)
print("latitude: %f, longitude: %f" % (locDict["latitude"], locDict["longitude"]))
```

I use this python code to get the location. You have to install chrome to make it run, i think :v

since I don't understand much, there're only my guessing, so please correct me if I'm wrong:
First, I use webdriver. I'm intended to open Chrome browser and use a javascript function from the web browser to get my location.

When run this code, a Chrome browser will open. Do not close it or the code won't work

then, the variable string is a bunch of javascript code. this code will be executed on the web browser, at [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) by using `driver.execute_script(string)`

The purpose of that javascript code is to get the locationg using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`, then write it inside a JSON string. Then, I created a `<p>` element with id="location", but the JSON string inside it, then attach then to the web. You'll see at the bottom of the website there's a json string down there after the code run to complete

After that, I need find the

element with id="location" in the web that I've previously inserted, `driver.find_element(By.ID, "location")`, get that JSON string, parsing it and get the value of latitude and longitude

You may ask why do I have to create a `<p>` element and put it on the web. Well, when execute the json string, I can't find a way to return the value of latitude and longitude from position.coords.latitude and position.coords.longitude, so I decided to write it on the web and find it later.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).